# What dns query TYPE is used to resolve the name in an SPF include statement?

Tags: spf

SPF records may contain include statements that list a dns name.  What is the query type you want to use to get the associated IPs for that name?  Do I need to query TXT records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use an request `TXT` records when resolving SPF. For a while there was a separate `SPF` DNS record type, but uptake was poor, and so it reverted to using `TXT` records in [RFC7208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3.1).